# Is there an electric field within a superconducting inductor?

Tags: electric-fields, potential, superconductivity, inductance

I have learned that the magnitude of the EMF (potential difference) between the terminals of an inductor is equal to L*di/dt. Does this imply that an electric field does indeed exist in an ideal inductor?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the sense that the charge carriers in the superconductor will experience a force when there's a changing flux.

Comment: If a inductor with zero resistance has a genuine potential difference/electric field, then how is the current not infinite?

Comment: Inertia - the electrons need to accelerate. And as they do so, they will counter the flux change. Eventually the loop completely excludes flux. This is the principle behind magnetic levitation etc.

Comment: @AndrewGuo, [$V=IZ$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm's_law#Reactive_circuits_with_time-varying_signals) for complex (capacitance and/or inductance) circuits.

Comment: Oh my, this went over me. I am still in highschool and am relatively new to the field of Electromagnetics--I have not learned about impendence or complex scalars yet. But EM is a field that never ceases to amaze and interest me and I will keep on learning things! One day, hopefully soon, I will understand exactly what that formula means.

Comment: @AndrewGuo - complex numbers are there to make a lot of hard math easier... but you first have to get your brain around them. Basically, you may know that when you drive an inductor with a $\sin$ wave of current, the voltage is a $\cos$ wave - that is, 90° out of phase. If you have a resistor in series, the phase angle changes (because some of the current will be generating voltage "in phase" across the resistor, and some will be "out of phase" on the inductor). It turns out that if you represent phase on a unit circle, and call the y direction "imaginary", the math becomes simple.

Comment: ... but the initial concepts are more complex than fit in 600 characters. However, if you have a good physics teacher you may be able to learn the basics of this in a couple of afternoons, and your ability to do "hard" electrical problems (capacitors and inductors) will be transformed.